# Installing Rust Compiler on Ipad Pro 2020

Tags: ipad, rust, rust-cargo

I have installed iSH Shell on my ipad pro 2020, and using apk to install rust and cargo (version 1.44.0) with the following command:

```
apk add rust
apk add cargo
```

When I tried to run `cargo build` or any rustc commands (e.g. `rustc -v`), it returned "Illegal Instruction".  I am not sure if anyone has successfully installed rust compiler on Alpine Linux (in my case it is Alpine Linux v3.12).  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/ish-app/ish/issues/67#issuecomment-609064073

Comment: Actually it appears that a lot of SSE instructions have since been implemented in the emulator, but it's currently blocked on MMX ones (tracked [here](https://github.com/ish-app/ish/issues/377)).